# Firebase local notifications

Tags: ios, firebase, localnotification

Is there any possibility to fire local notification when there is a callback from Firebase ? I've got a problem with threads I guess,

```
[Firebase setDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)];
```

Comment: Not enough info to help you. Could you please post more description info and code related to local notifications that you tried?

Comment: I would like to fire a local notification when new message was posted to Firebase by other user. Does Firebase stop when application is moved to background and do note sync data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve above functionality as follow.

1 ) `observeEventType` method is call when any changes occurs in `firebase database`

2 ) Implement `observeEventType` method as follow.

```
   // Below statement is point to your database.
   let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

   ref.observeEventType(.Value,withBlock:{ (snapshot) -> Void in
            print(snapshot.value)
            // Put your local notification code here...
   })
```