# Firebase with local notifications

Tags: ios, firebase, uilocalnotification

I want to set local notification with callback from Firebase when the callback will come.

self.messageQuery = [self.firebaseMessages queryStartingAtPriority:@(0)];

```
    [self.messageQuery observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot)
     {
          [self fireLocalNotification:snapshot.value];
     }];
```

The problem is that the callback do not work when application is in the background. Any solution for that ?

Comment: Please don't repost questions. It'll just be closed as a duplicate. Instead think what you can improve to your original question that gives it a better chance if being answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firebase local notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569816/firebase-local-notifications)